# How to post request using axios on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

how to **post request** using **axiox** on **reactjs**

I am building an simple **todo app**. I use **mongodb** and **nodejs** for the **backend** and **reactjs** for **frontend**.
Now i need to know how to **post request** using **axiox** on **reactjs**. Because i wanna stored all my data on my server. I make a **crud** api for that.

Thanks :)

Comment: did you try the [axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you are mentioning axios instead of axiox

Firstly you need to install [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) one of the ways is using npm , install its as a dev dependency from terminal/windows

```
npm install --save-dev axios
```

make sure to add the axios where ever you are making use of axios.

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

then you can use whatever request you want use axios for. Below is the code (GET request) from [axios npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) ,

```
axios.get('url')
  .then(function (response) {
    // You can do whatever you want to do with the response
  })
```

Make sure you add catch for error :

```
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

You can read more about on [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios)

If you want to know more about axios go here on [Medium](https://medium.com/@harinilabs/day-5-making-server-request-in-react-with-axios-8e85549caf62)

Answer (score 0):

This requires a much more detailed answer. Like what happens when you use arrow functions eg ..

```
axios.get('my/api/names')
      .then(function (response) {
// you get back an object with config,data,headers,request,status,statusText
// the api im currently working with hands out an array for the data bit of 
//the object then i can loop the data and use it whatever way i want.
        response.data.forEach( item => {console.log(item)}
      })
```

Im not 100 percent how this actually works but when your using the key word "then" its just your standard promise, after the then() its good to have a then.catch(err => {console.log(err)}) so it makes debugging that bit easier. The response is passed to the function in the form of an object so you can just use . notation to access the various things in that object. Im struggling a bit myself with axios, ive been reading up on it but there are some weird rules like { data } is required in some cases. Im hoping someone comes up with a better answer. axios is a really good tool and really helps when you have lots of API requests going off at the same time. You can use axios.all() to do all requests at the same time

```
axios.all(myArray.map(myArr => axios.get('/domain/thing/${myArr.names}/names')))
```

this bit of code just sends all your requests at the one time which can be handy in some cases. Keep reading the documentation and trying things out. I found it useful putting breakpoints in and watching the requests come through in the Network tab in chrome and looking at the way the code is interpreted in the Sources tab and watching the values change line by line. Also a good tool im using in React is MobX which is just a state management tool its pretty interesting and there a good course on eggheads.io which some German guy explains things really well. Best of luck with React